# InfoPath forms on client vs. hosted in Forms Server / MOSS

Tags: .net, sharepoint, moss, infopath

Is there a definitive list of functional differences between `InfoPath` forms in the `InfoPath` client vs. `InfoPath` forms hosted via Forms Server?

Talking to people who have worked with and deployed the technology before, they can't tell me anything specific except that more complex forms are not possible when you host them in Forms Server.

Can't find any documentation though, ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the official documentation of browser-enabled form limitations :

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/HA102040851033.aspx